# Consume API SharePoint Framework

Tags: spfx

I want to consume this api http://www.mindicador.cl/api with SPFX, i use jquery ajax but i haven't response (inclusive i haven't error descripction).

```
$.ajax("http://www.mindicador.cl/api",{  
  headers: { Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" },  
  async:true,  
  success: function (data) {  
      var items = data.d.results;  
      },error: function (data,a , b) {  
        alert("An error occurred. Please try again.");  
      }  
  });
```

i use WebRequestInfo too (like add-ins) but it response 404.

```
const context: SP.ClientContext = new SP.ClientContext(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
let request : SP.WebRequestInfo = new SP.WebRequestInfo;
request.set_url("http://www.mindicador.cl/api");
request.set_method("GET");
request.set_headers({ "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" });
var response : SP.WebResponseInfo = SP.WebProxy.invoke(context, request);
context.executeQueryAsync(() => {
  console.log(response.get_statusCode() + "," + response.get_headers());
}, (sender, args) => {
  console.log(args.get_message());
});
```

There is a mistake in the code or there are an another way to consume remote endpoints in SPFX? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PNP js instead,

This might help you:

[calling-external-apis-securely-from-sharepoint-framework](https://dev.office.com/blogs/calling-external-apis-securely-from-sharepoint-framework)

Comment: I have to use this way to consume the api. thx!

Answer (score 2):

This is a public API that isn't secured so you should be able to call it using the standard HttpClient that's a part of the SharePoint Framework. In your web part you should be able to do, something similar to:

```
this.context.httpClient
    .get('http://www.mindicador.cl/api', HttpClient.configurations.v1)
    .then((res: HttpClientResponse): Promise<any> => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .then((data: any): void => {
      // process your data here
    }, (err: any): void => {
      // handle error here
    });
```

For this code to work you have to include the following import statement:

```
import { HttpClient, HttpClientResponse } from '@microsoft/sp-http';
```

Comment: i have troubles with cors and sharepoint, i have to use azure function to secure the api, then i havent problems. thx!

Comment: It's ridiculous you have to use Azure functions. So much more hastle just to make a simple api call. @BrunoPalma have you found any other way? waldek is Azure Functions the only option? I'm trying to get Slack's API working but I'm also getting CORS errors.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to consume apis are in the link that **mohd tahir** said.
i use the following code on index.js (on the azure js function )

```
var request = require('request');
module.exports = function (context, req) {
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
request('http://www.mindicador.cl/api', function (error, response, body) {

    if (error) {
        context.log(error);
    }
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        context.res = {
            body: body,
            headers: {
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" : false,
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "contoso.sharepoint.com",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, OPTIONS",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" : "Content-Type, Set-Cookie, application/json",
                "Access-Control-Max-Age" : "86400"
            }
        };
        context.log(body);
    }
    context.done();
});
};
```

and add a package.json file

```
{
 "name": "API MiIndicadores Secure",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "Asegurar api MiIndicadores",
 "main": "index.js",
 "author": "bpalma",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "require": "^2.4.20"
 }
}
```

then npm install, then use the Waldek Mastykarz answer to consume the azure function changing the url. thx both!